# Помогите с побитовыми операциями

Tags: java

```
class Bitwise {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    int fs = 53; //В двоичном виде 00110101

    System.out.println("Флаг 1: "+(( (fs&1 > 0) ? "ВКЛ" : "выкл")));
    System.out.println("Флаг 2: "+(( (fs&2 > 0) ? "ВКЛ" : "выкл")));
    System.out.println("Флаг 3: "+(( (fs&4 > 0) ? "ВКЛ" : "выкл")));
    System.out.println("Флаг 4: "+(( (fs&8 > 0) ? "ВКЛ" : "выкл")));
    System.out.println("Флаг 5: "+(( (fs&16 > 0) ? "ВКЛ" : "выкл")));
    System.out.println("Флаг 6: "+(( (fs&32 > 0) ? "ВКЛ" : "выкл")));
    System.out.println("Флаг 7: "+(( (fs&64 > 0) ? "ВКЛ" : "выкл")));
    System.out.println("Флаг 8: "+(( (fs&128 > 0) ? "ВКЛ" : "выкл")));
    }
}
```

Вот пример из книги которую читаю и совершенно не понимаю вот этого `(fs&1 > 0)` и аналогичных далее выражений.

Программа не компилируется...

А в примере в ответе книги такой ответ должно получиться:

> Флаг 1: ВКЛ
>
> Флаг 2: выкл
>
> Флаг 3: ВКЛ
>
> Флаг 4: выкл
>
> Флаг 7: выкл
>
> Флаг 8: выкл
>
> Флаг 5: ВКЛ
>
> Флаг 6: ВЫКЛ

Comment: *Программа не компилируется...* - ошибка компиляции какая? Опубликовать в вопросе.

Comment: *не понимаю* - читать "тернарный оператор ?" Например вот http://javarush.ru/groups/posts/ternarnyj-operator

Comment: Похоже, вы неаккуратно переписали пример из книги, или издательство, выпустившее эту книгу, недобросовестно относится к своей работе. Выражение `fs & 1 > 0` в `Java` некорректно, так как оно трактуется как `fs & (1 > 0) `, где первый операнд -- `int`, а выражение в скобках имеет тип `boolean`. Операция `&` над операндами, из которых один `int`, а другой `boolean`, невозможна. И даже если бы была возможна, то выражение не имело бы смысла, поскольку `1 > 0` -- всегда `true`. Автор этого кода, очевидно, имел в виду `(fs & 1) > 0`.

Comment: А вот и ответ на мой вопрос, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так правильно.

```
System.out.println("Флаг 1: " + ((fs & 1) > 0 ? "ВКЛ" : "выкл"));
```

У оператора '>' приоритет больше, поэтому получалось `53 & (1 > 0)`, потому и не компилировалось. Изучите приоритет операторов, чтобы не повторять эту ошибку.

Еще я убрал лишние скобки.

---

Насчет побитовых операций: выражение с побитовым **И** как раз применяется для проверки определенного бита или битовой маски. Оно оставляет в числе только те его биты, которые равны 1 в маске. Степени двойки как раз имеют только один бит равный 1, поэтому такая запись проверит ровно один бит числа, разряд которого соответствует степени двойки.

Чтобы установить биты числа, используют **ИЛИ**:

```
flags |= mask;
```

Для сброса битов делают так:

```
flags &= ~mask;
```

Это инверсия маски и сброс в 0 всех битов которые равны 0 в инвертированной маске (1 в обычной).

Вместо числа может быть выражение вида `1 << 5`. Это сдвиг влево на 5 бит, он даст нам 32.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score -2):

(fs&1 > 0) 
53 - переводится в двоичное.110101. 1 переводится в двоичное - 1. Далее выполняется побитовое И. Результат - 
110101 > 0 - поэтому true - ВКЛ

Comment: на самом деле 53 & 1 будет 1

Comment: Да, накосячил. Спасибо.

Comment: Кроме того, что `53 & 1 != 53`, есть еще пара замечаний к этому ответу. Во-первых,  ничего никуда не переводится, а во-вторых выражение `s&1 > 0` вообще не имеет смысла и не компилируется. Не стоит так поспешно давать ответы, лучше сперва немного подумать.

Comment: @m.vokhm, всмысле не переводится? В десятичном виде считается?

Comment: @Alexey В компьютере все хранится и обрабатывается в двоичном виде. Десятичное 53 -- это двоичное 110101. Это просто разные способы записи одного и того же числа, которое ниоткуда никуда не переводится.